# How to slide position of a div when we drag other div upon it in java-script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript-typings

I have two divs I want that when I drag first div on second div than second div should move from its position.

```css
#mover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
}
 
#trigger {
     position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='mover'></div>
  <div id='trigger'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle `ondrop` event of green block.

```
function drop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("mover").style="left:80px";
   document.getElementById("trigger").style="left:200px";
}
```

Here is link for codepen.[Code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGjOpP)

I have red block as draggable. When you drop on green block, position will be changed.

Comment: i have already implemented this thing, what i want instead of this when i that when i drag first div upon second div than position of the second div should slide automatically(no style change)

Comment: actually i need this in pure java script